# Error de compilación POO Agregacion (C++)

Tags: c++, poo

En mi programa quiero que la clase CuentaSueldo se una a Persona, pero no quiero que se herede ya que hay muchas variables de Persona que no necesito. Cuando intento hacerlo me da:

> error: no matching function for call to 'CuentaSueldo::CuentaSueldo()'.

Aquí va el código:

```cpp
class CuentaSueldo {

private:
    int numCuenta;
    float saldo;
public:
    CuentaSueldo (int,float);
    void mostrar();
    void deposito();
    void extraccion();
    void pedir();
};

CuentaSueldo::CuentaSueldo (int _numCuenta, float _saldo){
numCuenta=_numCuenta;
saldo = _saldo;
}

class Persona {
  private:
    int dni;
    string nombre;
    string mail;
    bool alta;
    bool baja;
    string empresa;
    float sueldo;
    CuentaSueldo cuentasueldoo;

  public:
    Persona(int, string, string,bool,bool,string,float,CuentaSueldo);
    virtual void mostrar();
};

Persona::Persona (int _dni, string _nombre, string _mail,bool _alta,bool _baja,string _empresa,float _sueldo,CuentaSueldo _cuentasueldoo){
dni = _dni;
nombre = _nombre;
mail = _mail;
alta=_alta;
baja=_baja;
empresa=_empresa;
sueldo=_sueldo;
cuentasueldoo=_cuentasueldoo;
}
```

Comment: Posiblemente se refiera a que no existe un constructor por defecto y estás tratando de llamarlo en alguna parte.

Comment: @Mateo me ayudarias agregandolo a mi codigo?? Por favor

Comment: No puedo agregarlo directamente porque estaría respondiendo a la pregunta. Antes del constructor que tienes, escribe uno vacío: `CuentaSueldo(){ }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El error es claro y conciso, tal vez no lo entiendes por estar en inglés; te lo traduzco:

> ```
> error: no matching function for call to 'CuentaSueldo::CuentaSueldo()'.
> ```

> ```
> error: no se encuentra función coincidente para llamar a 'CuentaSueldo::CuentaSueldo()'.
> ```

Tal y como dice el error, no existe una función `CuentaSueldo::CuentaSueldo()`, esto se debe a la manera *especial* en que se tratan los constructores de objetos en [c++](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b):

Cuando se define un objeto, el compilador crea automáticamente cinco funciones:

- Constructor por defecto.
- Constructor de copia.
- Constructor de movimiento.
- Destructor.
- Operador de copia.

Gracias a ello, este código es válido:

```
struct S {}; // Objeto sin ninguna función

void f()
{
    S a;    // Se puede construir porque el compilador crea el constructor por defecto.
    S b{a}; // Se puede copiar porque el compilador crea el constructor de copia.
    S c{std::move(b)}; // Se puede mover porque el compilador crea el constructor de movimiento.
    S d = c; // Se puede copiar porque el compilador crea el operador de copia.
} // a, b, c y d se destuyen porque el compilador crea el destructor.
```

El "*problema*" es que el constructor por defecto creado por el compilador automáticamente deja de crearse en el momento en que el usuario declara un constructor, por lo tanto:

```
struct S { S(int); }; // Tiene un constructor que recibe un entero

void f()
{
    S a; // No se puede construir porque el compilador NO crea el constructor por defecto.
}
```

En otras palabras, el compilador te está diciendo:

> *Me dijiste que para crear un* `CuentaSueldo` *necesitaba un entero* (`int`) *y un número en coma flotante* (`float`) *¿Por qué ahora me pides que construya un `CuentaSueldo` sin parámetros?* (`CuentaSueldo::CuentaSueldo()`).

Y concretamente ¿Dónde estás pidiendo construir un `CuentaSueldo` sin parámetros?, pues en el constructor de `Persona`:

```
Persona::Persona (int _dni, string _nombre, string _mail,bool _alta,bool _baja,string _empresa,float _sueldo,CuentaSueldo _cuentasueldoo){
    dni = _dni;
    nombre = _nombre;
    mail = _mail;
    alta=_alta;
    baja=_baja;
    empresa=_empresa;
    sueldo=_sueldo;
    // Aquí el objeto 'cuentasueldoo' ya existe y no pudo construirse, de ahí el error
    cuentasueldoo=_cuentasueldoo;
}
```

Los sub-objetos de un objeto ya han sido creados en el momento en que se entra en el cuerpo del constructor (el cuerpo del constructor es el código contenido en las llaves `{` y `}` de la función constructor) de no ser así no podrías usarlos como los estás usando.

Entonces ¿de qué manera se puede inicializar un objeto que requiere parámetros de construcción antes de entrar en el cuerpo del constructor del objeto que lo contiene? Pues con la [lista de inicialización del constructor](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constructor):

```
Persona::Persona (int _dni, string _nombre, string _mail,bool _alta,bool _baja,string _empresa,float _sueldo,CuentaSueldo _cuentasueldoo) :
    // Construye el sub-objeto CuentaSueldo antes entrar en el cuerpo del constructor
    cuentasueldoo(_cuentasueldoo)
{
    dni = _dni;
    nombre = _nombre;
    mail = _mail;
    alta=_alta;
    baja=_baja;
    empresa=_empresa;
    sueldo=_sueldo;
}
```

Con el código anterior, estás llamando al constructor de copia (generado automáticamente) de `CuentaSueldo` antes de entrar en el cuerpo del constructor de `Persona` solucionando tu error.

También ser habría solucionado el error creando un constructor por defecto de `CuentaSueldo`:

```
class CuentaSueldo {

private:
    int numCuenta;
    float saldo;
public:
    CuentaSueldo (int,float);
    // Constructor por defecto, el 'default' es para que lo genere el compilador.
    CuentaSueldo () = default;
    void mostrar();
    void deposito();
    void extraccion();
    void pedir();
};
```